# Opening host app from safari extension and pass URL information

Tags: ios

I tried almost every single answer in SO but couldn't find this. Probably this is not possible. My requirement is, to open the host app when user tap the share extension (from safari) so that I can pass the shared URL to the host app.

I do not necessarily want to pop up the share sheet, just need to open the app and get the information. I know this is not what extensions are for. Extensions act independently even the host app is closed.

But is there any other way to achieve this specific scenario? If Im communicating between two apps this is possible with URL schemes. But what I need is to get shared URL from Safari and get that information to the host app (without doing anything in share extension). Is this possible?

Comment: so why not url scheme?

Comment: What about NSServices and menu that opens on right click?

Comment: @Lu_ its not possible to open an app with url scheme from a share extension